# Do I have to use an LG usb dongle?

Tags: wireless-networking

I recently bought a LG 37" tv, with wireless capabilities, and I was wondering if I could use a D-Link usb dongle instead of the LG one, and how so?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Judging from the warning at the bottom of this [LG website](http://lgknowledgebase.com/kb/index.php?View=entry&EntryID=6466), I'd guess they made sure their TVs only work with their own branded dongles.

*edit*
From some looking around on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003F9HH2W) I've deducted that the LG TVs that offer this wireless capability indeed only work with LG dongles, and that these range anywhere between 50 and 80 dollars, yikes!
Too bad, I wish I had better news for you.

Answer (score 0):

The LG tv is most likely running a variant of linux.  To use any usb dongle, that linux system needs a driver for it.  Now it's possible, likely even, that LG has made sure that the only wireless driver included with the kernel in the TV is the one for their dongle.  But you might get lucky if you choose another dongle that's known to be well supported in linux.

Comment: It may run that, but it's still a TV, not a computer. As such, it's off-topic on Super User.